printing " and ' in python
How can I print this ('''""") in Python?
I tried this but I got error:
print("'''"""")

and I tried this but I got error:
print(""""""'''"""""")


The term you're searching for is "escaping". Read the Python documentation, how to escape a quote character in the middle of a string can be found there.

Welcome to SO!  @Ulrich Eckhardt's comment should help you solve your problem, but my suggestions for future questions are:

use the formatting tools for your code (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
provide more information about the actual error messages you are seeing.


You can put a backslash character followed by a quote (\" or \').
This is called an escape sequence and Python will remove the backslash, and put just the quote in the string.
print("'''\"\"\"")
# or
print('\'\'\'"""')


I rolled back to my edit because you don't need to escape both kinds of quotes in the string, and I wanted to demonstrate that you can use either kind of quotes for the string delimiters.

@wjandrea Yes, you are right, thank you very much for your help
